# Backflow/check valve for domestic water: is there a design that is so reliable you can pretty much forget about them?

Tags: plumbing

I have an inexpensive check valve on the boiler fill to prevent backflow into the domestic water plumbing, but there's no check valve immediately after the water meter. We just had the meter replaced and the red dial indicator is moving both CW and CCW, which people say is caused by mains pressure fluctuations.  I was alarmed when I saw 37 gallons after only an hour or so when no water was running. I had only flushed one toilet, which isn't leaking. So I filled a 5-gallon bucket and the meter correctly registered 5 gallons consumed, but I'm still worried that the constant CCW and CW swings of the needle are advancing the gallons counter.

I went online to shop for valves and there's a wide range of prices and several different designs. If *reliability and ease of servicing or replacing are the most important criteria*, what design meets those criteria best?

So far, at least, I am trying to choose between (1) a dual-union press-fit spring-loaded valve, about $50, since if the valve fails it should be easy to replace because of the unions, or (2) a press-fit serviceable swing valve, without unions, at only $25, which couldn't be easily replaced having no unions but could be opened up for servicing, though I don't know what is involved in servicing a swing valve.

Is there something else I should consider?

[image: new water meter]

Comment: Where are you on this planet? There are likely plumbing code rules governing what sorts of backflow devices can be legally put on a boiler feed line where you live...

Comment: This would be for the domestic water line right after the meter, not the boiler. Pennsylvania USA.

Comment: So do you want to insert a check valve because you think you are possibly getting charged for water you are not using due to pressure fluctuations in the water main? The amounts of water flow associated with fluctuations in the city water main would be absolutely negligible because water is incompressible at the pressures involved. Don't make trouble for yourself by doing something that does not make sense. Do nothing and allow the currently inexplicable behavior to either go away or get worse so it can be properly diagnosed.

Comment: I have read different opinions on whether this results in billing inaccuracies. https://authoring-amwater-dev.awapps.com/paaw/Resources/PDF/bill%20insert.pdf?language_id=1    We have an expansion tank on a new indirect hot water heater (plumber did not install a check valve there) and also with a new washing machine we were getting bad water hammer so I installed a miniature expansion tank (about the size of an orange) right near the washing machine in the basement and set it to 75PSI. Our water pressure had been at 80PSI but it seems to have gone down 5PSI recently.

Comment: That miniature expansion tank hammer arrester was in addition to two new piston-style arresters which weren't solving the problem

Comment: I have often wondered if some water meters might have an integral check valve. I don't think they do, but don't know. Seems to me that water suppliers would want a customer-inaccessible tamper-proof check valve to protect the integrity of the public water supply. I do not believe that there are check valves in the meters where I live, but don't want to ask because I am concerned that they would want to know why I would want to know this.

Comment: We have an indirect hot water heater.  It has a dedicated expansion tank (in addition to the one on the boiler itself).  Would a pressure regulator be needed in addition to that expansion tank?

Comment: Integral check valve meter: https://www.neptunetg.com/products/watermeters/residential/t10dc/